# Bug after Samsung update | Monogame | Detecting viewport.height as devices width

Tags: android, xamarin, resolution, monogame

**UPDATE**

This issue have also been discussed in: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/2492

The problem is if the app is only allowed to run in Landscape orientation, not when you use Portrait or both.

---

Got a android game coded in monogame, where I got a `GraphicsDeviceManager` which are set to `FullScreen=true`.

I use the `GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height` and the `GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width` to determine the resolution of the device. 
This was working very good until I got an samsung update and had to turn FastDev off. 
The big mysterious problem:

When I debug with the pc, the height and width of the `viewport` is set correct. But when i unplug and play the app after 1-2 times the `viewport.Height` becomes the devices width, and the `viewport.Width` becomes the device height, which completely makes the game unplayable.

Its very hard to find the solution, since this is never happening when i debug and got the cable in from pc to the device.

Anyone got any ideas what it can be?

---

**I can now confirm that it is because of the samsung update**

I made worlds simplest android app to test it, just got a mainframe with a background image called "bg" and a spritefront printing out the viewport.Width and viewport.Height.

Here's the code:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace TestRes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        SpriteFont font;
        Rectangle _mainFrame;
        Texture2D _background;
        string text;

        public Game1()
        {
           graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
            //graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
           // graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 480;
            graphics.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting             
       /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
           text = "";
       }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            _background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Bilder/bg");
           _mainFrame = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,     this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("spriteFont1");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
             {
                 Exit();
             }
           text = "ScreenWidth: " + this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width + ", screenheight: " + this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
        // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
           graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

           spriteBatch.Begin();
           spriteBatch.Draw(_background, _mainFrame, Color.White);
           spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text, new Vector2(16, 1000), Color.White);
           spriteBatch.End();

           base.Draw(gameTime);
       }
    }
}
```

When deploying from VS everything is good, the viewport.width is the actual device width and the viewport.height is the actual device height. But when trying to deploy it from the Samsung Galaxy S4 active (sometimes you need to try 2-3 times) then all of a sudden Viewport.Height is the device Width and the other way around, which makes the background picture just cover a bit of the screen.

Have taken pictures to show it:

[image: photo]

Answer (score 0):

Checked in version 3.6  , and the bug is fixed.